understanding base locus of a divisor in an example
I want to build a concrete example illustrating the following result (from Cutkosky, Intro to Alg. Geometry, Lemma 13.25)
Let $X$ be a normal variety, D a Weil divisor on $X$, and $p \in X$. If $\mathcal{O}(D)_p$ is not invertible, then $p \in Base(|D|)$
For instance, take $X=V(xy-z^2)$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$ and $p$ the origin. Maybe take $D=V(x, z)$. Edit: How to calculate $Base(|D|)$ from the definition i.e $ \bigcap \ (f)+D$, where the intersection is over $f \in \mathcal{O}_(D)(X)$

Just the origin.

@Sasha Yes, that follows from the result and so I should clarify that my question was how I compute $Base(|D|)$ directly, like from its definition.

Your $X$ is a quadratic cone, your $D$ is its ruling, other divisors linearly equivalent to $D$ are the other rulings, and intersection of all (even of two) rulings is the origin.

Denote $D'=V(y,z)$.
Then $2D'=(y)$, $2D=(x)$, $D+D'=(z)$. They are all principal.
Then clearly $D\sim D'$. In particular, the base locus is contained in $D\cap D'=P$ which is the origin. On the other hand, the origin $P$ is contained in the base locus as $D$ is not Cartier at $P$. So the base locus is exactly $\{P\}$.
